# C# Get BIOS Events using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, bios

I am trying to retrieve BIOS Event log so I can see low level hardware errors such as thermal events from recent model Dell Laptops. I know they have their own tool to do this but it doesn't do specifically what I need.

I know I can get some high level BIOS data using **Win32_BIOS** via WMI however I don't see the BIOS event log data that way which is what I am after. Anyone know how to get this or what WMI branch this is under in C# via Winforms (.Net 4.0) ?

(PS. Please don't suggest an alternative tool or discussing it with Dell as those options have already been explored and are not a direction I want to go. Thanks)

Comment: Show us some code.  This is a programming website; if you're not trying to write a program, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: I am asking for the API Call; why would code matter? I could only show you non-working code. This is a high level question, not a low level one that I would have spec's for.